# Lightdm displaying wrong username

Tags: users, configuration, lightdm

I have an Ubuntu 19.10-based distro with LightDM installed. I changed the username recently, but lightdm keeps displaying the old username. Is there a way I can fix this?

I have tried fiddling with `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` with no success.

Attached are pictures demonstrating what I am talking about.

Is this a lightdm issue? Or some other configuration that hasn't been modified? Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you changed username? By creating a new one? Did you reboot your machine?

Comment: @binarym I used `usermod -l new-user-name old-user-name` and then modified `/etc/passwd` after I renamed the home directory because for some odd reason usermod didn't want to change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the name `batcastle` is the username, while `live` is the so-called fingername. Both are stored in the file `/etc/passwd`. The username (that is the login name) is somewhat more complicated to change, because most likely you want to have the home directory called `/home/$(whoami)`.

To change the username, use `usermod`.

```
usermod -l newusername -d /home/newusername -m oldusername
```

You may want to change the ownerships of the files and directories accordingly. This should not be necessary, because actually, on the filesystem, the owner information is only stored as the numerical ID:

```
chown -R newusername /home/newusername
```

To change the fingername, use `chfn`:

```
chfn -f 'John Doe' username
```

For more details, please refer to the `man` pages of these commands.

Comment: That `chfn` command worked! Thank you!